# How two different values can store in one memory space in C language?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory, memory-address

In the below code in 7th and 8th line the variables are taking same address space but in 9th and 10th line I can see the values are different. and I compared the address as well and it's showing same address space. when I'm printing the addresses of the array in the below for loop it's getting allocation from different address space which is ok but then why it was allocated to different address space previously? why the address is changed? and how in one address space two different values can store?

I have pasted the code the output the code below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
    int x = 50, *p, *q;
    int arr[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    p = &x;
    q = &arr[0];
    printf("\nValue : %d", &q+1);
    printf("\nValue : %d", &p);
    printf("\nValue : %d", *(q+1));
    printf("\nValue : %d", *p);
    if(&p == &q+1){
        printf("\nSame");
    }
    printf("\nfor loop");
    for(int i=0; i<=10; i++){
        printf("\nValue : %d", &q[i]);
    }
}
```

```
output:
Value : 6422292
Value : 6422292
Value : 2
Value : 50
Same
for loop
Value : 6422248
Value : 6422252
Value : 6422256
Value : 6422260
Value : 6422264
Value : 6422268
Value : 6422272
Value : 6422276
Value : 6422280
Value : 6422284
Value : 6422288
```

Comment: "*In the below code in 7th and 8th line the variables are taking same address space*"- No, they are not. Also, `%d` expects an integer, not a pointer, so technically your printing has undefined behavior. Use `%p` to print pointers

Comment: Sidenote: `%d` is not the proper conversion specifier for printing pointers. Use `%p`, like so: `printf("\nValue : %p", (void*)(&q + 1));`

Comment: You’re not printing out the addresses they point to, just the addresses of the variables, and adjusting one. &p is the address of p, you want to output just p if you want to know where value of \*p  comes from

Comment: Also, your loop is going out of bounds of the array, which is also undefined behavior

Comment: @RemyLebeau isn't it legal to point to the element after the last element of the array? In the loop only the address of `q[10]` is taken without accessing the memory.

Comment: @Gerhardh getting an address to the end of the array is OK, yes, as long as you don't dereference it. What's debatable is the syntax you use to get that address.  `q[i]` is equivalent to `*(q+i)`, which would be UB when `i` is out of bounds, but `&*(q+i)` is equivalent to `(q+i)`, which is not UB when `i` is at the end of the array. The question is where a dereference occurs or not in that situation. Best not to risk it. Use the safer syntax in that case.

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("\nValue : %d", &q+1);
printf("\nValue : %d", &p);
printf("\nValue : %d", *(q+1));
```

In the first line, you are adding one to the address of `q` since `&q` is the address of `q`.

In the last line, you are adding one to the value of `q` and then dereferencing it.

Adding one to the address of `q` and one to the value of `q` don't give you the same *anything* so there is no reason any differences should surprise you.

Answer (score 1):

The variables are not stored on the same address.
You are using %d, %d is for integer values, thus output has undefined behaviour.

use %p for pointers.

Answer (score 0):

`&q` is the address of the pointer variable `q`.
`&q+1` is the address of the first byte *after* `q`.

`&p` is the address of the pointer variable `p`.

`if (&p == &q+1)` tests if `p` is stored in the first byte after `q`. It is quite possible that the compiler chose to store it there. Or it could be stored anywhere else, it's all up to the compiler to select addresses for each variable.